# Scrapy splash - loop saves all values to only one item

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Scrapy with splash to scrape values of Javascript based website. Code works fine and spider scrapes all interesting values. Problem is that it saves all of those values to only one item.

```
class Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test"
    start_urls = ["http://example.com/results"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths = ('//div[contains(@class, "products")]'), ),
             callback="parse",
             follow=False),)

    def start_requests(self):
       for url in self.start_urls:

           yield SplashRequest(url,callback=self.parse, endpoint='render.html', args={'wait':25.5})

    def parse(self, response):

       product_list = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "products")]').extract()

       for items in product_list:
          item=TestItem()
          item['CompanyName'] = response.xpath('').extract()
          item['Revenue'] = response.xpath('').extract()
          item['Tag'] = response.xpath('').extract()
          yield item
```

I don't see anything wrong with above code. All of my items reside within one div. But there are multpile divs containing those items. Website shows a lot of results on one page from which i need to take those values. For example, in `div products` there is 10 different divs containing said items.

Output is as follows:

```
CompanyName,Tagline,Revenue
XcompanyName, YcomapnyName, ZCompanyName
Xtagline, Ytagline, Ztagline
Xrevenue, Yrevenue, Zrevenue
```

While i want it to be:

```
CompanyName,Tagline,Revenue
XcompanyName, Ytagline, Zrevenue
YcompanyName, Ytagline, Yrevenue
ZcompanyName, Ztagline, Zrevenue
```

Website CSS:

```
<div class="products">
            <div id="ember1" class="product ember-view"><a href="/product/NameCompany" id="ember1" class="product-link ember-view">  <div class="product-card-header">
    <div id="ember1" class="product-card-logo ember-view"><img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/" id="ember1" class="product-avatar-img ember-view">
</div>
    <div class="product-card-header-t">
      <span class="product-card__name">NameCompany</span>
      <span class="product-card__tagline">Simple</span>
    </div>
  </div>

<!---->
    <div class="product-card-revenue">
      <div class="product-card-revenue-t">
        <span class="product-card-revenue-r">
          $0
          <span class="product-card-slash">/</span>
          <span class="product-card-period">month</span>
        </span>

        <span class="product-revenue">
<!---->          reported
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

If i use `extract_first()` in my xpath for items, format of the file is correct but it only saves information from one div and omits rest.

Comment: Provide the link, please.

Comment: maybe you need `items.xpath('').extract()` instead of `response.xpath('').extract()`

Comment: I've added part of CSS were all of the items are extracted from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Umair answer was right

```
    def parse_attr(self, response):

       for items in response.xpath(''):
          item = TestItem()
          item['CompanyName'] = items.xpath('').extract()
          item['Revenue'] = items.xpath('').extract()
          item['Tag'] = items.xpath('').extract()
          yield item
```

I needed to pass `items` (NOT item) inside of the loop, not response object. Response was defined in scope of divs in question. Now output has correct format.